# Node js Session Creating Different cookies for every request using Postgres and expression session

Tags: node.js, postgresql, session, cookies

Here is my code

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieparser = require('cookie-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var session = require('express-session');
var PostgreSqlStore = require('connect-pg-simple')(session);

//var mongoose=require('mongoose');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
//session starts
app.use(cookieparser());

var sessionOptions = {
    secret: "secret",
    resave: true,
    //cookie :{ maxAge : 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000},
    cookie: { httpOnly: false },
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new PostgreSqlStore({
        conString: "postgres://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:5432/session"
    })
};
app.use(session(sessionOptions));


//session ends

require('./routes/routes.js')(app);


app.listen(4001);
//exports.start = start;
exports.app = app;
```

While inserting on login
req.session('userid')=email;

the database has one record , but for  next request it inserts another cookie record . I want to make it only once for authentication purpose. and i want to know better way of simple auth using postgres.

Comment: Try setting saveUnititialized to true, also in the browser see what the age is of the cookie.

Comment: Tried every possible combination but it keeps on inserting value for ever api call

Comment: Whats the age of the cookie? im guessing it is getting rewritten